# Python, Mac OS X NSUserNotification, action button

Tags: python, macos, nsusernotification

I am having some trouble understanding how to get an NSUserNotification's action button to do something using Python. I think I understand that "userNotificationCenter_didActivateNotification_" is called when a user clicks the button?

But I can't work out how to receive the notification and use it to call a custom method - i am using a call to os.system("say") just as a test

I have tried setting the class's delegate to self but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Cheers

Adam

This is what I have as a class that I call from another script when something is completed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Foundation, objc
import AppKit
import sys
import os
import logging

from Foundation import NSUserNotification
from Foundation import NSUserNotificationCenter
from optparse import OptionParser


class Notification_osx:     

    def __init__(self, item,proyecto):

        self.item = item
        notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
        notification.setTitle_("Notification: " + proyecto)
        notification.setSubtitle_("Un archivo nuevo esta disponible:")
        notification.setInformativeText_(item)
        notification.setHasActionButton_(True);
        notification.setActionButtonTitle_("Donde?")

        home = os.path.expanduser("~")
        LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(home,'Desktop','sync.log')
        logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.debug(notification.description)


        # notification.setUserInfo_({"action":"open_url", "value":item})

        # if options.sound:
        #    notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")

        center = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
        center.setDelegate_(self)
        center.deliverNotification_(notification)
        # center.didActivateNotification_(notification)

    def userNotificationCenter_shouldPresentNotification_(self, center, notification):
        os.system("say hola")
        return True

    def userNotificationCenter_didDeliverNotification_(self, center, notification):
        os.system("say hola")


    def userNotificationCenter_didActivateNotification_(self, center, notification):

        # userInfo = notification.userInfo()
        os.system("say hola")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the notification activation with this code, not sure it answer your question as you seems to have an action button

```
import Foundation, objc

NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')
NSObject = objc.lookUpClass('NSObject')


class NotificationDelegator(NSObject):

    def userNotificationCenter_didActivateNotification_(self, center, notification):
        print "user notification center"

    def userNotificationCenter_shouldPresentNotification_(self, center, notification):
        return True

delegator = NotificationDelegator.alloc().init()


def notify(title, subtitle, info_text, delay=1, sound=False, userInfo={}):
    """ Python method to show a desktop notification on Mountain Lion. Where:
        title: Title of notification
        subtitle: Subtitle of notification
        info_text: Informative text of notification
        delay: Delay (in seconds) before showing the notification
        sound: Play the default notification sound
        userInfo: a dictionary that can be used to handle clicks in your
                  app's applicationDidFinishLaunching:aNotification method
    """
    notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
    notification.setTitle_(title)
    notification.setSubtitle_(subtitle)
    notification.setInformativeText_(info_text)
    notification.setUserInfo_(userInfo)
    if sound:
        notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")
    center = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
    center.setDelegate_(delegator)
    center.deliverNotification_(notification)
```